# How to get Smartsheet published sheet's url?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'd like to get url from a Smartsheet published sheet by Python.

Below is my code but it gives me error message.

```
 # Publish the sheet

sheetToPublish = smartsheet_client.Sheets.set_publish_status(

sheet.id,       # sheet_id

smartsheet.models.SheetPublish({

  'readOnlyFullEnabled': True

})

)

publish_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_publish_status(

  sheet.id)       # sheet_id
﻿
﻿print(publish_sheet.readOnlyFullUrl)
```

Here is the error message,

```
AttributeError: 'SheetPublish' object has no attribute 'readOnlyFullUrl'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When troubleshooting property names in situations like this, it's often helpful to look at the SDK source code on GitHub. In this case, the [sheet_publish.py](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/smartsheet/models/sheet_publish.py) model that's defined in the SDK source code shows that the correct syntax for this property name is: `read_only_full_url` (not `readOnlyFullUrl`).

[image: sheet_publish.py property definition]

Comment: This is awesome! thank you for your answer I will read through SDK srouce.